# Bind 'this' to NavigationBarRouteMapper non-function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a NavBarRouteMapper object that I pass to my navbar. However, in the onpress function of one of the buttons I need to access the state, but I'm not sure how to bind 'this' to the object, since it is a non-function. Relevant code as follows

```
 class app extends Component {
   state: {
     sideMenuIsOpen: boolean,
   };
   constructor(props: Object) {
      super(props);
     this.state = {
       sideMenuIsOpen: false,
     };
   };

static NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
     LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
       if (index > 0) {
         return (
           <SimpleButton
            // TODO: Make this work, Menu button needs to go to this
            // The problem is here. this.state is undefined
             onPress={console.log(this.state)}
             customText="Back"
             style={styles.navBarLeftButton}
             textStyle={styles.navBarButtonText}
           />
         );
       }
     },
     RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
       // TODO change add button for admins
       switch (route.title) {
         case "Login":
          return null;
         default:
           return (
             <SimpleButton
               onPress={() => {
                 navigator.push({
                   title: "Profile",
                   component: Profile,
                 });
               }}
               customText="Add"
               style={styles.navBarRightButton}
               textStyle={styles.navBarButtonText}
             />
          );
       }
     },
     Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
       return (
         <Text style={styles.navBarTitleText}>{route.title}</Text>
       );
     },
   };


render() {
     return (
       <SideMenu
         menu={<Menu navigate={this.navigate} />}
         isOpen={this.state.sideMenuIsOpen}
        >
         <Navigator
           ref="rootNavigator"
           initialRoute={{
             title: "Login",
             component: LoginScene,
             navigator: this.refs.rootNavigator,
           }}
           renderScene = {this.renderScene}

           navigationBar={
             <Navigator.NavigationBar
              // Since this is an object, I can't bind 'this' to it,
              // and the documentation calls for it to be passed an object
              routeMapper={app.NavigationBarRouteMapper}
              style={styles.navBar}
              />
           }
        />
      </SideMenu>
    );
  };
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to return the parent's state from the child onClick?  If so you can add an onClick which calls the parent onClick that you can pass to the child via props.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {test: "testing 1 2 3"};
  },
  clickMethod: function () {
    alert(this.state.test);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div onClick={this.clickMethod}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Also if you had a list of components where each component needs to pass a unique piece of data to the parent you can do so using bind.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {test: "testing 1 2 3"};
  },
  clickMethod: function (argument) {
    alert(argument);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div onClick={this.clickMethod.bind(this, "custom argument")}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chrshawkes/64eef3xm/1/

Comment: The problem isn't with the onclick happening in the <SimpleButton> class, its that I can't pass the state into the NavigationBarRouteMapper in any way that I know of.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of pattern you are using, your outermost component should have the state.  If you're using a flux pattern than you should have actions which trigger state changes so your onclick would fire a dispatch method to a store which changes state or something to that effect, I'm not 100% familiar with flux at the moment.

Comment: The outermost component does have a state. However, when calling 'this' inside of NavigationBarRouteMapper, it gets the state for that instead of the outermost component. Since I can't bind the outermost object to the RouteMapper, I'm not sure how I would pass props into it, since it is not a React Component.

Comment: So, in my example I provided an example of a child component obtaining state from the parent.  Your parent could get state from it's parent.  However, this is what the Flux pattern was built for, having a global state so you don't have to resort to such hackery.  However, my example would work assuming your component is a descendant of this component you want to get state from.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you meant by the flux pattern. Just figured it out. Thank you